# Is there a class to store a generic range in std::ranges?

Tags: c++, iterator, transform, std-ranges

Is there a concrete template class (not a concept) to store a generic range (i.e. pair of iterators/sentinels) in std Ranges?

Given a pair of iterator I can always store it in `std::pair<iterator_type, interator_type>` and access to them as `.first` and `.second`, but in reality they could be named `.begin()` and `.end()`.

I found this very old proposal, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3350.html#index_1overview

The reason is that I have function that takes a pair of iterators (as in the old days) and should return a (const) view of them, so it seem that I need to return a concrete type.

```
template<class It>
a_range<It> my_func(It first, It last){
   ...
   return a_range<It>(first, last);
}
```

I didn't find anything in the Range library.
The closest I could find is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_interface.

```
template<class It>
auto my_func(It first, It last){
   ...
   struct View : public std::ranges::view_interface<View> {
     View(It begin, It end) : m_begin(begin), m_end(){}
     auto begin() const { return m_begin; }
     auto end() const { return m_end; }
   private:
     It m_begin, m_end;
   };
   return View{first, last};
}
```

or, more to the point:

```
   ...
   return  std::ranges::transform_view{ View{first, last}, [](auto const& a)->decltype(a){return a;});
}
```

Is this going in the right direction?

To begin with, I would like to keep access category (e.g. random access, etc), which this doesn't seem to preserve.
Also using `transform` to protect (as const) the elements seems an overkill, but that is secondary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for a range that can be created from a pair of iterators (or more generally, iterator and sentinel).  `std::ranges::subrange` does that. It inherits from `view_interface` that you mentioned.

Comment: Nice. Interesting name for something that is not necesarely a proper subrange. Seems to be it, let me try. Only in C++ range is a concept and subrange is a concrete (although template) type.

Comment: @alfC That's why it's not named proper_subrange :)